# Clean-up needed: [direct-message]

Tags: discussion, clean-up, meta-tags

I draw your attention to the tag: [direct-message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct-message).

Only nine messages, but...

There is, of course no tag wiki and no usage guidance. By itself, the tag is useless; it requires a companion tag to give it context.

Mostly it seems to be tied to questions about Twitter direct messages, but there are also questions on

- Instagram
- Facebook
- A web app recommendation request (closed)

So, this would seem to be a meta tag and needs to be cleaned up. I don't know that the tag is needed at all. If it is, then it should be specific to the app, e.g., [twitter-direct-message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-direct-message), [instagram-direct-message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instagram-direct-message), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All questions have been cleaned up. An excerpt and tag wiki was created for [twitter-direct-message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-direct-message).